# PHP Log includes WARNING, NOTICE, and Fatal error on same line

Tags: php, logging, fpm

To test out my php error logging, I threw a random `throw` line into my `index.php`.

```php
throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
```

I literally just wanted to get some output into my error log, so i copied that line from somewhere - the variables are kinda irrelevant, in fact they aren't defined, which throws an error, but that's exactly what I wanted...

Anyway, here's the error output, and I'm just trying to make sense of it:

```
[23-Feb-2022 14:02:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 393450 said into stderr: "  thrown in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 2"
[23-Feb-2022 14:07:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 393449 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $message in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 2"
[23-Feb-2022 14:07:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 393449 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $severity in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 2"
[23-Feb-2022 14:07:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 393449 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $filename in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 2"
[23-Feb-2022 14:07:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 393449 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $lineno in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 2"
[23-Feb-2022 14:07:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 393449 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException in /var/www/mysite/index.php:2"
```

Specifically, the last log has a label of `WARNING`, while the message contains `NOTICE` as well as `Fatal error`. This line of course crashes the process as a runtime error, so "Fatal error" seems correct, yet the line is labeled as `NOTICE` and `WARNING`. Why? Is there a way to get Fatal errors to be recorded as `ERROR`? Furthermore, why does the line include both `NOTICE` and `WARNING`, that is, why are there two labels and why are they different?

Additional info - I have `catch_workers_output = yes` in my fpm config.

Comment: What web server? I've never toggled `catch_workers_output`. Looked at `error_log` and `log_errors`?

Comment: That's just a layer removed, everything going to stderr from the process is logged as a notice, regardless of the PHP error level. Only thing I have in my php-fpm logs are notices from the child processes starting and exiting. Application errors are sent to my server error logs.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71880: _"I confirm: Since 7.3 you can set 'decorate_workers_output = no' in your php.ini wich fixes the problem."_ - try that one.